# Hide and show spans with a specific class

Tags: javascript, dom, html

I'm i'm trying to display songs made by an artist when i click the artist's name.
Here's my HTML

```
<div id="artists">
<span class="artist" id="Eminem" onclick="showSongs("Eminem")">Eminem</span>
</div>

<div id="songs">
<span style="display:none;" class="Eminem" id="Eminem - Survival" onclick="playSong('Eminem - Survival');">Survival</span>
</div>
```

And here is my Javascript

```
function showSongs(artist) {
document.getElementsByClassName(artist).styles.display="inline";
}
```

This is not all my code, I have more artists and more songs.
but the point is that i want the songs from an artist to display when i click the artists name
I have googled it for a while now, All i found was that i had to display span tags as inline.
If you need more information just ask and i'll edit the post

Comment: I think you should change `inline` to `inline-block`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, adjust the artist name you are sending to use single quotes, you are breaking the string by using double quotes.

```
<span class="artist" id="Eminem" onclick="showSongs('Eminem')">Eminem</span>
```

Then when you get elements by class name you are retrieving a collection and need to loop through them. Shown below:

```
function showSongs(artist) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(artist);
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].style.display="inline";
  }
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f72Wk/).

Comment: Glad you got it working, don't forget to mark as answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Ah yes, see the other answers for the other half of the problem.

This code should work, the only thing I see wrong with it is this line:

```
<span class="artist" id="Eminem" onclick="showSongs("Eminem")">Eminem</span>
```

You should use single quotes inside the showSongs call:

```
<span class="artist" id="Eminem" onclick="showSongs('Eminem')">Eminem</span>
```

If that does not solve the problem, it is probably caused by some other code on the page.

Comment: Did not work by itself, had to adjust the javascript to what @Goose awnsered

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array-like collection. I don't think you can change the style this way.. Maybe you could try this :

```
function showSongs(artist) {
    var artists = document.getElementsByClassName(artist);
    for(var i = 0; i < artists.length; i++) {
        artists[i].style.display="inline";
    }
}
```

Would be a lot easier with [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/LVRGZ/3/**

```
<div id="artists">
    <span class="artist" onclick="showSongs('Eminem')">Eminem</span>
</div>

<div id="Eminem" style="display:none;">
    <span id="Eminem - Survival" onclick="playSong('Eminem - Survival');">Survival</span><br/>
    <span id="Another Song" onclick="playSong('Eminem - 2');">Another Song</span><br/>
    <span id="A Third Song" onclick="playSong('Eminem - 3');">A Third Song</span><br/>
</div>

<script>
showSongs=function(id) {
    alert("Showing "+id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='';
}
</script>
```